# XSD: Not allowing null values when maxOccurs="unbounded"

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an xsd code which looks like this :

```
<xsd:complexType name="Parent" >
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="child1" type="tns:TimeWindow" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xsd:element name="child2" type="tns:SlotRange" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

When the above code is being converted to xml , there is a required field added to child1 even when the minOccurs is set to zero. This results in validation errors when no child1 object is present.

```
<structure name="Parent">
    <member name="child1" target="_TimeWindowVector"/> 
    <member name="child2" target="SlotRange"/> 
</structure> 
<required target="Parent$child1"/>
```

Comment: I can't see any relationship between these documents

Comment: *When the above code is being converted to xml* - it's already XML. XSD is written in XML. Do you mean when an XML instance is being validated against the XSD? If so we need to see the instance to be able to help you. The XML you have provided is not an instance of that XSD. There is no visible relationship there.

Comment: Yes , when an instance is validated against the XSD, it is invalidated if the child1 is null even when I have set the minOccurs to zero.

Comment: Please provide a [*Minimal, **COMPLETE**, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the problem.  Thanks.